# Cannot use Python variable for file name of CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I would like to use figures of timestamps in Pandas dataframe for a file name of CSV output, but encountered an error message.

Here are the procedures.

Here is a link of source CSV file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UttGIugFXS2sAybiiXleIcPS4NNVf8-T6zt8cdMH_u4/edit#gid=0

1. Read a CSV file, and created a Pandas dataframe as 'df'.
2. Extracted figures of timestamps from the dataframe, and merged them as 'df_time'.

```
df_start = df['start'].min()
df_end = df['end'].max()
df_time = str(df_start) + '-' + str(df_end)
```

3. Then, I tried to use 'df_time' for the file name of CSV output.

```
df.to_csv('test_' + df_time + '.csv')
```

After this, I encountered the following error.

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-09dbe0d815ec> in <module>
----> 1 df.to_csv('test_' + df_time + '.csv')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3202             decimal=decimal,
   3203         )
-> 3204         formatter.save()
   3205 
   3206         if path_or_buf is None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in save(self)
    186                 self.mode,
    187                 encoding=self.encoding,
--> 188                 compression=dict(self.compression_args, method=self.compression),
    189             )
    190             close = True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text)
    426         if encoding:
    427             # Encoding
--> 428             f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
    429         elif is_text:
    430             # No explicit encoding

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'test_2020/11/10 7:00:00-2020/11/9 7:30:00.csv'
```

I use Python 3.7.6, and found some solutions for '[Errno 22] Invalid argument'. However, I cannot find similar case with this situation.

I would appreciate if you provide an advice to avoid this error.

Comment: Can you try naming the file without the character / and :?

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed / and :, and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save the file with certain characters like '/', adjust timestamp variable `df_time` in readable way and then save it to csv.

Comment: I removed : and / from the variable, and the problem just solved. Thank you so much.